# While import product custom options throws error in magento 2

Tags: import, custom-options, csv, magento-2.2.5

While trying to import custom options for product throws the below error. Please provide me a solution

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '4953' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO
>   `catalog_product_option_type_value`
>   (`option_type_id`,`sort_order`,`sku`,`option_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?),
>   (?, ?, ?, ?), (?,